# In cbc mode how do you find the key when you have the plaintext and the ciphertext using openssl?

Tags: cryptography

In cbc mode how do you find the key when you have the plaintext and the ciphertext using openssl?

Okay so say that this command (below) was executed, and the key is a secret. but we know the plaintext and the ciphertext, how could I (using openssl) find the key that was used to encrypt this message?

This was the command used to encrypt the plaintext

```
$openssl aes-128-cbc -nosalt -k **** -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.bin
```

Comment: You would brute-force the *password* `-k`. Don't confuse passwords and keys.

Answer (score 1):

In any concept of real-time you don't.

The caveat is if the key is a password and not a random key or derived key, in that case you try passwords from know password lists, there are many on the Internet. This is why using passwords is ill-advised, at a minimum they need to have a key derived from them by an algorithm such as PBKDF2.

AES and other modern ciphers are designed to be secure against attacks, that the key is required in order to decrypt the information. You need the key.

Comment: okay thank you. this was a problem on a test i had in class , and the teacher never went over it, and i was trying to figure it out on my own, but i had no luck. but thank you for the info , an help.